# Excel VBA Macro: How do I delete all sheets except one sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

To be specific, I want to delete all sheets except Sheet6 which is the code name of a sheet, but I can't seem to make my code work.

```
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  If ws <> ThisWorkbook.Sheet6 Then

      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      ws.Delete
      Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  End If

  Next ws
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.CodeName <> "Sheet6" Then ws.Delete
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: This suffers from deleting items in a collection while iterating forwards.  You will find that it will skip worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate with no vars.

```
application.displayalerts = false

with ThisWorkbook
    if .worksheets("sheet6").index > 1 then _
        .worksheets("sheet6").move before:=.sheets(1)
    do while .sheets.count > 1
        .sheets(2).delete
    loop
end with

application.displayalerts = true
```

Answer (score 0):

When deleting, always iterate backwards (although Jeeped's answer has a different way of addressing this).

```
    Dim iterator as long
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For iterator = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(iterator)
            if .CodeName <> "Sheet6" Then .Delete
        End With
    Next iterator
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```